# How to convert many thousands of lines of VBScript to C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript, qtp

I have a collection of about 10,000 small VBScript programs (50-100 lines each) and a small collection of larger ones, and I'm looking for a way to convert them to C# without resorting to by-hand transliteration.  The programs are automated test cases for a web application, written for HP/Mercury's QuickTest Pro, and I'm trying to turn them into test cases for Selenium.  Luckily, the tests appear to be well-written, using a library of building blocks and idioms (the larger programs), so the test cases actually resemble a domain-specific language more than they do VBScript, and the QTP-ness is well-buried inside the libraries.

Ideally, what I'm searching for is a tool that can do the syntactic transformation from VBScript to C# for both the dsl-ish test cases and also the more complicated building-block libraries.  That would leave me with a manual cleanup of the libraries, and probably very little work on the test cases.  If I could find a VBScript-to-VB.NET translator, I'd take that also, as I suspect I could compile the VB.NET and then de-compile to C# using .NET Relector or something similar.  Plan B is to write a translator of my own for the test cases, since they're in a very straight-line style, but it wouldn't help with the libraries.

Any suyggestions?  I haven't written a compiler in at least 15 years, and while I haven't forgotten how, I'm not looking forward to it - least of all for VBScript!

Comment: In the end, I wrote a translator by hand, because the content of these programs was tightly constrained.  ho1's VB6 suggestion was a great idea I would never have thought of, and if Visual Studio hadn't made it so hard for me to get the files *into* a project so I could convert them, I'd have definitely used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most vbscript is valid VB6 code, so one option would be to just rename them from .vbs to whatever it was VB6 used and then add them all to a VB6 project and see if the VB6 - VB.Net upgrade wizard that comes with some versions of Visual Studio can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

[GreatMigrations](http://greatmigrations.com/) has a tool that does a good job converting VB6 to C# (and other languages).  I know the company is willing to work with organizations to tailor the product to their specific needs.